# TEZ as execution at job level

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

How to selectively set **TEZ** as execution engine for PIG jobs?

We can set execution engine in **pig.properties** but its at the cluster impacts all the jobs of cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible if the jobs are submitted through Templeton.

Example of PowerShell usage

```
New-AzureHDInsightPigJobDefinition -Query $QueryString -StatusFolder $statusFolder -Arguments @("-x”, “tez")
```

Example of CURL usage:

```
curl -s -d file=<file name> -d arg=-v -d arg=-x -d arg=tez 'https://<dnsname.azurehdinsight.net>/templeton/v1/pig?user.name=admin'
```

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiny_bits/archive/2015/09/19/pig-tez-as-execution-at-job-level.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the execution engine as parameter as shown below, for mapreduce it is mr and for tez it is tez.
`pig -useHCatalog -Dexectype=mr -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=<queue name> -param_file               dummy.param dummy.pig`